# (chrome.socket.read) My returned ArrayBuffer() is getting truncated (cut off)

Tags: sockets, truncate, google-chrome-app, arraybuffer

I am using Chrome Apps to do a programming assignment for class and the `ArrayBuffer()` returned from the callback of `chrome.socket.read()` keeps truncating a >3 kb `POST` message at 1 kb. like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2965
Origin: http://ggp.stanford.edu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://ggp.stanford.edu/applications/040100.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

(start x040100 robot ((role robot)(<= (base (cell ?M ?N ?P)) (row ?M) (col ?N) (piece ?P))(<= (base (captures ?M)) (scoremap ?M ?N))(<= (base (step ?N)) (succ ?M ?N))(<= (input robot (move ?M1 ?N1 ?M2 ?N2)) (row ?M1) (col ?N1) (knightmove ?M1 ?N1 ?M2 ?N2))(row 1)(row 2)(row 3)(row 4)(row 5)(col 1)(col 2)(col 3)(piece knight)(piece pawn)(piece blank)(init (cell 1 1 knight))(init (cell 1 2 pawn))(init (cell 1 3 pawn))(init (cell 2 1 pawn))(init (cell 2 2 pawn))(init (cell 2 3 pawn))(init (cell 3 1 pawn))(init (cell 3 2 pawn))(init (cell 3 3 pawn))(init (cell 4 1
```

I tried setting the buffer size high and many other things, even downloading other people's server apps and modifying those to prove to myself it's not just me. Is there a 1 kb limit? Am I making a mistake?

Comment: TCP buffers are like buses - if the first one is full, another one will be arriving shortly.

Comment: TY, that did it, I never thought to repeat socket.read until the message is complete. You saved me